# Cusp is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n=1}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, geometric-topology

> Question: Show that the Cusp is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n=1}$ and thus is a topological manifold.

The ordinary Cusp is given by $f\left ( x,y \right )=x^{2}-y^{3}=0$

In 2D, $f\left ( x,0 \right )=x^{2}$
Let the Cusp C and $\mathbb{R}$ be topological space.

Define:

> $f: C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>
> $x \mapsto x^2 $

Clearly, f is a bijective map.

To show that f is homeomorphic, it remains to to show that f and $f^{-1}$ is continuous.
It remains to be shown that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ maps open sets between the given topological spaces.

Here is a cross road.

Recall: $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a topological manifold

So clearly, here $\mathbb{R}^{n=1}$ is locally euclidean and there must exists a function f that maps open sets from $\mathbb{R}^{n=1}$ to the Cusp.
Assume otherwise and arrive at a contradiction.

Or

Recall: If M is a topological space and U is an open subset of M then U is a topological manifold.

The second theorem seems more direct. $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n=1}$ and so is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n=1}$.
By definition, the basis for the subspace topology on C is the collection of an arbitrary union of open sets in C and so C is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n=1}$.
Therefore, C is a topological manifold and so C is a homeomorphism.

Have I blundered anywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A possible homeomeorphism $f:\mathbb R\to C$ is given by $f(t)=(t^3,t^2)$.
The inverse homeomorphism is then described by

$$f^{-1}:C\to \mathbb R:\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(x,y) \mapsto\frac xy  \;\operatorname{for}   \;(x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
(0,0)\mapsto 0 \\
\end{array}\right.$$